# JpaRepository Returns a list with duplicated objects

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm trying to figure out how i can correctly get 2 object from a jpa repository

Now this is my repository:

```
@Transactional
public interface CompanyDao extends JpaRepository<Company, Integer> {
    //HQL query
    @Query("SELECT e,b from EstimateOptions e,BillNumber b inner join e.Company company inner join company.user user where user.email = :userName\n")
    List <Object[]>testQuery(@Param("userName") String userName);
}
```

But when i test this inside the Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getcompanyestimateoptions")
public List getCompanyEstimateOptions(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal user) {



    LOGGER.info("TEST LIST");
    List<Object[]> listObjects = companyDao.testQuery(user.getName());

    for (Object object[] : listObjects) {
        EstimateOptions estimateOptions = (EstimateOptions) object[0];
        BillNumber billNumber = (BillNumber) object[1];

        LOGGER.info(estimateOptions.toString());
        LOGGER.info(billNumber.toString());
        LOGGER.info(object.toString());
    }

    LOGGER.info("START ESTIMATEOPTIONS QUERY");


    return listObjects;

}
```

Entity User

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_user")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fkIdCompanyUser")
    private Company company = new Company();
}
```

Entity billnumber

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="tbl_BillNumber")
public class BillNumber {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_BillNumber")
    private Integer id;
}
```

Entity EstimateOptions

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="tbl_Estimateoptions")
public class EstimateOptions {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EstimateOptions.class);


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_Estimateoptions")
    private Integer id;
}
```

Entity Company

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="tbl_Company")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_company")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="company", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    @OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fkIdCompanyBill")
    private BillNumber billnumber = new BillNumber();

    @OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fkIdCompanyEstimateOption")
    private EstimateOptions estimateOptions = new EstimateOptions();
}
```

This is the output of the sql:

```
Hibernate: select distinct estimateop0_.id_estimateoptions as id_estim1_6_0_, billnumber1_.id_bill_number as id_bill_1_0_1_, estimateop0_.estimate_customer_note as estimate2_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_model as estimate3_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_model_primary_color as estimate4_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_model_secondary_color as estimate5_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_model_tertiary_color as estimate6_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_personal_note as estimate7_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_terms as estimate8_6_0_, billnumber1_.credit_note_numberprefix as credit_n2_0_1_, billnumber1_.credit_note_numbersuffix as credit_n3_0_1_, billnumber1_.credit_note_start_number as credit_n4_0_1_, billnumber1_.customers_id_on as customer5_0_1_, billnumber1_.estimate_numberprefix as estimate6_0_1_, billnumber1_.estimate_numbersuffix as estimate7_0_1_, billnumber1_.estimate_start_number as estimate8_0_1_, billnumber1_.every_year_new_date_on as every_ye9_0_1_, billnumber1_.invoice_numberprefix as invoice10_0_1_, billnumber1_.invoice_numbersuffix as invoice11_0_1_, billnumber1_.invoice_project_number as invoice12_0_1_, billnumber1_.invoice_start_number as invoice13_0_1_, billnumber1_.month_on as month_o14_0_1_, billnumber1_.project_number_numberprefix as project15_0_1_, billnumber1_.project_number_on as project16_0_1_, billnumber1_.project_number_total_prefix_numbers as project17_0_1_, billnumber1_.total_prefix_numbers as total_p18_0_1_, billnumber1_.year_on as year_on19_0_1_ from tbl_estimateoptions estimateop0_ inner join tbl_company company2_ on estimateop0_.id_estimateoptions=company2_.fk_id_company_estimate_option inner join tbl_user user3_ on company2_.id_company=user3_.fk_id_company_user cross join tbl_bill_number billnumber1_ where user3_.email=?
Hibernate: select company0_.id_company as id_compa1_2_2_, company0_.bank_account as bank_acc2_2_2_, company0_.fk_id_company_bill as fk_id_c18_2_2_, company0_.city as city3_2_2_, company0_.company_name as company_4_2_2_, company0_.contact_email as contact_5_2_2_, company0_.contact_telephone as contact_6_2_2_, company0_.country as country7_2_2_, company0_.dateformat as dateform8_2_2_, company0_.default_currency as default_9_2_2_, company0_.fk_id_company_estimate_option as fk_id_c19_2_2_, company0_.hide_tax_number_on_estimate as hide_ta10_2_2_, company0_.house_number as house_n11_2_2_, company0_.street as street12_2_2_, company0_.tax_number as tax_num13_2_2_, company0_.tax_number_enabled as tax_num14_2_2_, company0_.website as website15_2_2_, company0_.website_enabled as website16_2_2_, company0_.zip_code as zip_cod17_2_2_, billnumber1_.id_bill_number as id_bill_1_0_0_, billnumber1_.credit_note_numberprefix as credit_n2_0_0_, billnumber1_.credit_note_numbersuffix as credit_n3_0_0_, billnumber1_.credit_note_start_number as credit_n4_0_0_, billnumber1_.customers_id_on as customer5_0_0_, billnumber1_.estimate_numberprefix as estimate6_0_0_, billnumber1_.estimate_numbersuffix as estimate7_0_0_, billnumber1_.estimate_start_number as estimate8_0_0_, billnumber1_.every_year_new_date_on as every_ye9_0_0_, billnumber1_.invoice_numberprefix as invoice10_0_0_, billnumber1_.invoice_numbersuffix as invoice11_0_0_, billnumber1_.invoice_project_number as invoice12_0_0_, billnumber1_.invoice_start_number as invoice13_0_0_, billnumber1_.month_on as month_o14_0_0_, billnumber1_.project_number_numberprefix as project15_0_0_, billnumber1_.project_number_on as project16_0_0_, billnumber1_.project_number_total_prefix_numbers as project17_0_0_, billnumber1_.total_prefix_numbers as total_p18_0_0_, billnumber1_.year_on as year_on19_0_0_, estimateop2_.id_estimateoptions as id_estim1_6_1_, estimateop2_.estimate_customer_note as estimate2_6_1_, estimateop2_.estimate_model as estimate3_6_1_, estimateop2_.estimate_model_primary_color as estimate4_6_1_, estimateop2_.estimate_model_secondary_color as estimate5_6_1_, estimateop2_.estimate_model_tertiary_color as estimate6_6_1_, estimateop2_.estimate_personal_note as estimate7_6_1_, estimateop2_.estimate_terms as estimate8_6_1_ from tbl_company company0_ left outer join tbl_bill_number billnumber1_ on company0_.fk_id_company_bill=billnumber1_.id_bill_number left outer join tbl_estimateoptions estimateop2_ on company0_.fk_id_company_estimate_option=estimateop2_.id_estimateoptions where company0_.fk_id_company_estimate_option=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id_user as id_user1_9_3_, user0_.authority as authorit2_9_3_, user0_.fk_id_company_user as fk_id_co8_9_3_, user0_.email as email3_9_3_, user0_.enabled as enabled4_9_3_, user0_.first_name as first_na5_9_3_, user0_.last_name as last_nam6_9_3_, user0_.password as password7_9_3_, company1_.id_company as id_compa1_2_0_, company1_.bank_account as bank_acc2_2_0_, company1_.fk_id_company_bill as
```

The list contains `BillNumber` and `EstimateOptions` twice. So when i send this to the front end i get array with 2 duplicated information. What did i do wrong ?

**EDIT**

WHEN using following query

```
@Query("SELECT distinct  e,b from EstimateOptions e,BillNumber b join fetch e.Company company join fetch company.user user where user.email = :userName\n")
List <Object[]>testQuery(@Param("userName") String userName);
```

the SQL output is now :

```
 Hibernate: select distinct estimateop0_.id_estimateoptions as id_estim1_6_0_, billnumber1_.id_bill_number as id_bill_1_0_1_, company2_.id_company as id_compa1_2_2_, user3_.id_user as id_user1_9_3_, estimateop0_.estimate_customer_note as estimate2_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_model as estimate3_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_model_primary_color as estimate4_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_model_secondary_color as estimate5_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_model_tertiary_color as estimate6_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_personal_note as estimate7_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_terms as estimate8_6_0_, billnumber1_.credit_note_numberprefix as credit_n2_0_1_, billnumber1_.credit_note_numbersuffix as credit_n3_0_1_, billnumber1_.credit_note_start_number as credit_n4_0_1_, billnumber1_.customers_id_on as customer5_0_1_, billnumber1_.estimate_numberprefix as estimate6_0_1_, billnumber1_.estimate_numbersuffix as estimate7_0_1_, billnumber1_.estimate_start_number as estimate8_0_1_, billnumber1_.every_year_new_date_on as every_ye9_0_1_, billnumber1_.invoice_numberprefix as invoice10_0_1_, billnumber1_.invoice_numbersuffix as invoice11_0_1_, billnumber1_.invoice_project_number as invoice12_0_1_, billnumber1_.invoice_start_number as invoice13_0_1_, billnumber1_.month_on as month_o14_0_1_, billnumber1_.project_number_numberprefix as project15_0_1_, billnumber1_.project_number_on as project16_0_1_, billnumber1_.project_number_total_prefix_numbers as project17_0_1_, billnumber1_.total_prefix_numbers as total_p18_0_1_, billnumber1_.year_on as year_on19_0_1_, company2_.bank_account as bank_acc2_2_2_, company2_.fk_id_company_bill as fk_id_c18_2_2_, company2_.city as city3_2_2_, company2_.company_name as company_4_2_2_, company2_.contact_email as contact_5_2_2_, company2_.contact_telephone as contact_6_2_2_, company2_.country as country7_2_2_, company2_.dateformat as dateform8_2_2_, company2_.default_currency as default_9_2_2_, company2_.fk_id_company_estimate_option as fk_id_c19_2_2_, company2_.hide_tax_number_on_estimate as hide_ta10_2_2_, company2_.house_number as house_n11_2_2_, company2_.street as street12_2_2_, company2_.tax_number as tax_num13_2_2_, company2_.tax_number_enabled as tax_num14_2_2_, company2_.website as website15_2_2_, company2_.website_enabled as website16_2_2_, company2_.zip_code as zip_cod17_2_2_, user3_.authority as authorit2_9_3_, user3_.fk_id_company_user as fk_id_co8_9_3_, user3_.email as email3_9_3_, user3_.enabled as enabled4_9_3_, user3_.first_name as first_na5_9_3_, user3_.last_name as last_nam6_9_3_, user3_.password as password7_9_3_ from tbl_estimateoptions estimateop0_ inner join tbl_company company2_ on estimateop0_.id_estimateoptions=company2_.fk_id_company_estimate_option inner join tbl_user user3_ on company2_.id_company=user3_.fk_id_company_user cross join tbl_bill_number billnumber1_ where user3_.email=?
```

But the list still contains duplicated information.

Comment: please add your entities. is equals/hashCode overriden?

Comment: I also don't see any relation between e and b so it'll probably join any b to the selected e's. That might not be your immediate problem but is likely to cause some in the future.

Comment: i added my entity's too. Any clue's what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: does select distinct change anything?

Comment: do you have equals or hashcode methods in your entiies?

Comment: @OskarDajnowicz distinct does not change anything. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Simo no i do not have any equals or hashcode inside my entities

Comment: ok, please  set the level to debug or the showsql property of hibernate to true. if you run the sql query direct to your database, are there objects twice too?

Comment: @Simo i do get some object twice.

Comment: please try this query:
@Query("SELECT company  from Company company where company.user.email = :userName\n")
    List <Company>testQuery(@Param("userName") String userName);

and the getCompanyEstimateOptions method : List<Company> listObjects = companyDao.testQuery(user.getName());

    for (Company c : listObjects) {
        EstimateOptions estimateOptions = c.getEstimateOptions();
        BillNumber billNumber = c.getBillNumber(); ....

Comment: Probably this is caused by the inner joins and the relationships between the joined tables. If you use fetch instead of inner does it make any difference? Also depending on the dependencies between the tables also consider the left join.

Comment: @Simo If i use your query (which works) i get the whole object company with all his properties. but i only want the data of billnumber and estimateoption, let's say for example i also have an object mapped images in company with a one to one it would also be in the list. Any idea’s how I could accomplish that.

Comment: if there are properties like a image, you can set the fetch type to LAZY. or try this query: "SELECT company.estimateOptions, company.billNumber from Company company where compa.... " but this will return a list of Object[] instead of Company. I would prefer to configure the fetch type. And you should not use the entity in your frontend. create another object (a data tranfer object) and use this

Comment: @anna i also tried your suggestion, It also gets me closer to the solution. I update this into my question but i still get a duplicated information.

Comment: but you added a join... that was not my intention: the fully query:
SELECT company.estimateOptions, company.billNumber from Company company  where company.user.email = :userName

Comment: Also keep in mind that a Set(instead of List) will fix this problem in case you don't find any other more valid solution.

Comment: @anna I think i found a possible solution if you want could you give your opinion about this. Because i'm not quite sure if it is the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a possible solution for this problem. In the end i reconfigured the query like this. Now i get an object with EstimateOptions and BillNumber without all the settings of company or user. There are also no more duplicated objects.

```
@Query("from EstimateOptions options,BillNumber billnumber join fetch billnumber.Company company2 join fetch company2.user user2  join fetch options.Company company join fetch company.user user where user.email = :userName and user2.email = :userName")
Set<Object[]> testQuery6(@Param("userName") String userName);
```

But i still have some duplicate information in my query

```
Hibernate: select estimateop0_.id_estimateoptions as id_estim1_6_0_, company4_.id_company as id_compa1_2_1_, user5_.id_user as id_user1_9_2_, billnumber1_.id_bill_number as id_bill_1_0_3_, company2_.id_company as id_compa1_2_4_, user3_.id_user as id_user1_9_5_, estimateop0_.estimate_customer_note as estimate2_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_model as estimate3_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_model_primary_color as estimate4_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_model_secondary_color as estimate5_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_model_tertiary_color as estimate6_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_personal_note as estimate7_6_0_, estimateop0_.estimate_terms as estimate8_6_0_, company4_.bank_account as bank_acc2_2_1_, company4_.fk_id_company_bill as fk_id_c18_2_1_, company4_.city as city3_2_1_, company4_.company_name as company_4_2_1_, company4_.contact_email as contact_5_2_1_, company4_.contact_telephone as contact_6_2_1_, company4_.country as country7_2_1_, company4_.dateformat as dateform8_2_1_, company4_.default_currency as default_9_2_1_, company4_.fk_id_company_estimate_option as fk_id_c19_2_1_, company4_.hide_tax_number_on_estimate as hide_ta10_2_1_, company4_.house_number as house_n11_2_1_, company4_.street as street12_2_1_, company4_.tax_number as tax_num13_2_1_, company4_.tax_number_enabled as tax_num14_2_1_, company4_.website as website15_2_1_, company4_.website_enabled as website16_2_1_, company4_.zip_code as zip_cod17_2_1_, user5_.authority as authorit2_9_2_, user5_.fk_id_company_user as fk_id_co8_9_2_, user5_.email as email3_9_2_, user5_.enabled as enabled4_9_2_, user5_.first_name as first_na5_9_2_, user5_.last_name as last_nam6_9_2_, user5_.password as password7_9_2_, billnumber1_.credit_note_numberprefix as credit_n2_0_3_, billnumber1_.credit_note_numbersuffix as credit_n3_0_3_, billnumber1_.credit_note_start_number as credit_n4_0_3_, billnumber1_.customers_id_on as customer5_0_3_, billnumber1_.estimate_numberprefix as estimate6_0_3_, billnumber1_.estimate_numbersuffix as estimate7_0_3_, billnumber1_.estimate_start_number as estimate8_0_3_, billnumber1_.every_year_new_date_on as every_ye9_0_3_, billnumber1_.invoice_numberprefix as invoice10_0_3_, billnumber1_.invoice_numbersuffix as invoice11_0_3_, billnumber1_.invoice_project_number as invoice12_0_3_, billnumber1_.invoice_start_number as invoice13_0_3_, billnumber1_.month_on as month_o14_0_3_, billnumber1_.project_number_numberprefix as project15_0_3_, billnumber1_.project_number_on as project16_0_3_, billnumber1_.project_number_total_prefix_numbers as project17_0_3_, billnumber1_.total_prefix_numbers as total_p18_0_3_, billnumber1_.year_on as year_on19_0_3_, company2_.bank_account as bank_acc2_2_4_, company2_.fk_id_company_bill as fk_id_c18_2_4_, company2_.city as city3_2_4_, company2_.company_name as company_4_2_4_, company2_.contact_email as contact_5_2_4_, company2_.contact_telephone as contact_6_2_4_, company2_.country as country7_2_4_, company2_.dateformat as dateform8_2_4_, company2_.default_currency as default_9_2_4_, company2_.fk_id_company_estimate_option as fk_id_c19_2_4_, company2_.hide_tax_number_on_estimate as hide_ta10_2_4_, company2_.house_number as house_n11_2_4_, company2_.street as street12_2_4_, company2_.tax_number as tax_num13_2_4_, company2_.tax_number_enabled as tax_num14_2_4_, company2_.website as website15_2_4_, company2_.website_enabled as website16_2_4_, company2_.zip_code as zip_cod17_2_4_, user3_.authority as authorit2_9_5_, user3_.fk_id_company_user as fk_id_co8_9_5_, user3_.email as email3_9_5_, user3_.enabled as enabled4_9_5_, user3_.first_name as first_na5_9_5_, user3_.last_name as last_nam6_9_5_, user3_.password as password7_9_5_ from tbl_estimateoptions estimateop0_ inner join tbl_company company4_ on estimateop0_.id_estimateoptions=company4_.fk_id_company_estimate_option inner join tbl_user user5_ on company4_.id_company=user5_.fk_id_company_user cross join tbl_bill_number billnumber1_ inner join tbl_company company2_ on billnumber1_.id_bill_number=company2_.fk_id_company_bill inner join tbl_user user3_ on company2_.id_company=user3_.fk_id_company_user where user5_.email=? and user3_.email=?
Hibernate: select company0_.id_company as id_compa1_2_2_, company0_.bank_account as bank_acc2_2_2_, company0_.fk_id_company_bill as fk_id_c18_2_2_, company0_.city as city3_2_2_, company0_.company_name as company_4_2_2_, company0_.contact_email as contact_5_2_2_, company0_.contact_telephone as contact_6_2_2_, company0_.country as country7_2_2_, company0_.dateformat as dateform8_2_2_, company0_.default_currency as default_9_2_2_, company0_.fk_id_company_estimate_option as fk_id_c19_2_2_, company0_.hide_tax_number_on_estimate as hide_ta10_2_2_, company0_.house_number as house_n11_2_2_, company0_.street as street12_2_2_, company0_.tax_number as tax_num13_2_2_, company0_.tax_number_enabled as tax_num14_2_2_, company0_.website as website15_2_2_, company0_.website_enabled as website16_2_2_, company0_.zip_code as zip_cod17_2_2_, billnumber1_.id_bill_number as id_bill_1_0_0_, billnumber1_.credit_note_numberprefix as credit_n2_0_0_, billnumber1_.credit_note_numbersuffix as credit_n3_0_0_, billnumber1_.credit_note_start_number as credit_n4_0_0_, billnumber1_.customers_id_on as customer5_0_0_, billnumber1_.estimate_numberprefix as estimate6_0_0_, billnumber1_.estimate_numbersuffix as estimate7_0_0_, billnumber1_.estimate_start_number as estimate8_0_0_, billnumber1_.every_year_new_date_on as every_ye9_0_0_, billnumber1_.invoice_numberprefix as invoice10_0_0_, billnumber1_.invoice_numbersuffix as invoice11_0_0_, billnumber1_.invoice_project_number as invoice12_0_0_, billnumber1_.invoice_start_number as invoice13_0_0_, billnumber1_.month_on as month_o14_0_0_, billnumber1_.project_number_numberprefix as project15_0_0_, billnumber1_.project_number_on as project16_0_0_, billnumber1_.project_number_total_prefix_numbers as project17_0_0_, billnumber1_.total_prefix_numbers as total_p18_0_0_, billnumber1_.year_on as year_on19_0_0_, estimateop2_.id_estimateoptions as id_estim1_6_1_, estimateop2_.estimate_customer_note as estimate2_6_1_, estimateop2_.estimate_model as estimate3_6_1_, estimateop2_.estimate_model_primary_color as estimate4_6_1_, estimateop2_.estimate_model_secondary_color as estimate5_6_1_, estimateop2_.estimate_model_tertiary_color as estimate6_6_1_, estimateop2_.estimate_personal_note as estimate7_6_1_, estimateop2_.estimate_terms as estimate8_6_1_ from tbl_company company0_ left outer join tbl_bill_number billnumber1_ on company0_.fk_id_company_bill=billnumber1_.id_bill_number left outer join tbl_estimateoptions estimateop2_ on company0_.fk_id_company_estimate_option=estimateop2_.id_estimateoptions where company0_.fk_id_company_bill=?
```

I will not accept my answer because there is probably a better way to solve this. But its more like a fix around this. Feel free to leave comment for further improvements about this.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the cross join in the generated query. 'A CROSS JOIN is a JOIN operation that produces the Cartesian product of two tables. Unlike other JOIN operators, it does not let you specify a join clause. You may, however, specify a WHERE clause in the SELECT statement.'

Comment: What will be the result if you use this? select company.estimateOptions, company.billnumber from Company company join fetch company.user user where user.email = :userName. Will it work?

Comment: @anna Sorry for the late response but i actually redesign the whole entities structure i think you where right and this could be best solution.